# What is the purpose of a diode in parallel with a BJT in a MOSFET drive circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

This circuit shows a *complementary emitter follower* driving an IRF 150 MOSFET. The textbook says that a diode D provides a path for the discharge of the base-emitter junction capacitance of transistor Q1. I don't really understand why this is necessary. Can't the base-emitter capacitance of Q1 discharge through R2 only? And what forces the charge to discharge through the diode only in this configuration then?

*Note: the 2 BJTs are driven by a square wave (0-12V).*

[image]

Comment: which textbook are we talking about?

Comment: Please cite book and perhaps more text. || I've never seen that done and the need is inobvious. IT may be clever and I'm missing it, but ... .

Comment: Why to drive MOSFET need emmiter follover? It is usual use for current amplfying.

Comment: @user263983 Gate capacitance.

Comment: @user263983 Current amplification is the entire point here, it takes a lot of current to switch a power MOSFET quickly.

Comment: It might be Zenner diode, overvoltage protection.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bottom pnp transistor and the "high" frequency model of both devices, the base emitter capacitance (-Cbe+) discharges through the diode capacitance, and then to ground (note polarity).

[image: High frequency model of BJT (polarity depends on npn/pnp)]

[image: High frequency model of diode]

I ran a quick simulation with common parts and didn't make much difference at 5kHz. [image: Simulation with LTspice]